# Laravel & PostGres - Migration down() will not drop table (TimeScaleDB Extension)

Tags: laravel

Here is what `create_facts_table` looks like:

```php
class CreateFactsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('pgsql')->create('facts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('entry_id');
            $table->string('tag');
            $table->timestampTz('time');
            $table->double('sensor_value');

            $table->index(['entry_id', 'tag', 'time']);
            $table->unique(['entry_id', 'tag', 'time']);
        });

        DB::connection('pgsql')->statement('SELECT create_hypertable(\'facts\', \'time\');');
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        // Tried both, neither would delete the table
        Schema::connection('pgsql')->dropIfExists('facts');
        //DB::connection('pgsql')->statement('DROP TABLE facts;');
    }
}
```

I don't get any error from `down()`. I am able to login as the DB user specified in my `.env` file and run `DROP TABLE facts`.

When I run `php artisan migration:fresh` `up()` fails to create the table and throws a duplicate table error:

```
Duplicate table: 7 ERROR:  relation "facts" already exists
```

After manually deleting the table, I can then run `php artisan migration:fresh`. I must specify `connection('pgsql')` as I'm using multiple databases. Semi-unrelated, but I'm using TimeScaleDB extension (hence `create_hypertable()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug a bit deeper on this recently. I hadn't directly mentioned I was using the TimeScaleDB extension (`'SELECT create_hypertable(\'facts\', \'time\');'`).

I updated the title of the question incase someone lands here from Google in the future.

Here is what I have learned:
When `php artisan migration:fresh` is run, it attempts to drop all tables in batch and does not use the `down()` method. TimeScaleDB hypertables **cannot** be deleted in batch.

The solution is to use `php artisan migration:refresh` instead which will run the defined `drop()` operations for each table.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69105447/5449796